# Peer authentication failed using psql with user and db created with ansible postgresql_user

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, ansible

What's wrong with my usage of ansible `postgresql_user`:

```
 - name: Create user and grant access to the database
    become_user: postgres
    become: yes
    postgresql_user:
      db: '{{db_name}}'
      name: '{{db_user}}'
      password: '{{db_password}}'
      priv: ALL
      state: present
```

The database with proper name is created and when I enter psql being postgres user:

```
                                  List of databases
    Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 app-andi | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
            |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
            |          |          |             |             | andi=CTc/postgres
 postgres   | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 template0  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
            |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

problem:

when trying to:

`psql -d "app-andi" -U andi -W`

and providing password given in ansible variable I end up with:

`psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "andi"`

USING:
ansible 2.3.1.0
Vagrant 1.9.4

DOCS:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/postgresql_user_module.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html

Answer (score 0):

problem was completly ansible un-related.

Just connect like this:

`psql -d "app-andi" -U andi -W -h 127.0.0.1`